# Implementing drawCard function for cards game

Tags: java, eclipse, playing-cards

I am new to coding in java and this is a little game I am making related to cards. The game consists of two players and each player is assign half of a shuffled deck(26 cards to each player). In each turn, the players `drawCard`(one card for one player in each turn) from their `deck` and add them to the `tableDeck` which is empty at the first turn. If the `faceValue` of the cards drawn by the players matches with each other then the player drawing at the last takes the cards and adds them to his `deck`. The player wins who runs out of his cards first.

```
public enum Color {
SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS;
}
public enum FaceValue {
TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE;
}
```

Card class

```
public class Card {
private Color color;
private FaceValue faceValue;

public Card(Color color, FaceValue faceValue) {
    this.color = color;
    this.faceValue = faceValue;
}
```

Deck class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Deck {

private List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
private Card card;

public Deck() {
    for (Color c : Color.values()) {
        for (FaceValue f : FaceValue.values()) {
            this.card = new Card(c, f);
            deck.add(card);
            ((Deck) deck).shuffle();
        }
    }
}
public void shuffle() {
    Collections.shuffle(this.deck); 
}
}
```

Player class(incomplete)

```
public class Player {

private Deck deck;

public Player(){
    this.deck= new Deck();
    deck.shuffle();
}

public drawCard(){
}
}
```

I want to implement the `drawCard` method for the player class.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: You are shuffling the deck twice. Do you want to deal from the top or the bottom of the deck?

Comment: I think `drawCard` should be defined in the `Deck` class. And no I am just making sense for what to do? Why am I stuck?

Comment: I have removed the line `((Deck) deck).shuffle();` from the `Deck` class.

Comment: Hi, you need to at least provide an idea or something. Add the draw card into the deck class and provide the deck to the player, do not construct it inside the class. You can get the first one then. deck.get(0) since it;s suffled.